# train_test_split - without random, with original order

Tags: machine-learning, split, scikit-learn

I want to use `train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)`, but I don't want the data to be random - I want the first 80% of the data to be train and the last 20% to be test. Can it be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought `train_test_split` was still using random while initial shuffle is off. This is actually can be solved with a simple `shuffle=False` arg:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42,shuffle=False)
```

Comment: For the sake of clarity you could ommit the `random_state = 42`